# how to bypass making same comparison twice within a vector

Tags: .net, vb.net, console

first of all sorry for my english if it is bad.

Im writing this program that ask you to store in a vector "competitors" in this case im storing 4 and in the second column im storing their "score". the way im setting their score is comparing them like in this example.

which game has better story? (1)gameA or (2)gameB

typing "2" gives gameB +1 on its score.
so i can know better which one is truly better when comparing all of them

the code looks like this (ive changed a little to fit the example)

```
Dim comp(3, 1) As String
Dim resp As Char

For cont = 0 To 3
  WriteLine("Insert Game " & cont + 1)
  comp(cont, 0) = ReadLine()
Next
```

until here i store the 4 games in column 1, and the next thing is that i compare every one, like a play off (or "eliminatoria").

```
WriteLine("which game has better story?")

For cont1 = 0 To 3
  For cont2 = 0 To 3
```

--
here i do this thing so the same game doesn't compare whit itself

```
    If comp(cont1, 0) = comp(cont2, 0) Then
      resp = "3"
```

--

```
    Else
      WriteLine("(1)" & comp(cont1, 0) & " VS (2)" & comp(cont2, 0))
      resp = ReadLine()
    End If

    Select Case resp

      Case "1"
        comp(cont1, 1) = comp(cont1, 1) + 1

      Case "2"
        comp(cont2, 1) = comp(cont2, 1) + 1

      case "3"

    End Select
  Next
Next
```

so everything is fine, GameA compares to GameB, you type "2" an and B wins +1 on score which goes to the second column.
**the thing is while program advance GameB comes to compare again eventually with GameA.**

How you guys would do to fix this? so any game compares with another only once.

***THANKS FOR YOUR TIME***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter the loops like this:

```
For cont1 = 0 To 2
    For cont2 = cont1 + 1 To 3
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Compare {0} to {1}", cont1, cont2))
    Next
Next
```

Outputs:

```
Compare 0 to 1
Compare 0 to 2
Compare 0 to 3
Compare 1 to 2
Compare 1 to 3
Compare 2 to 3
```